# getValue method in CAPL does not return expected value

Tags: string, capl, canoe

I am developing a CANoe simulation which takes a string from a panel, processes it in CAPL and provides info about that string further.

See the following snippet:

```
char myString[17];
int x=0;

x = getValue(envVar, myString);

write(myString);
write("%d",x);
```

The snippet should do the following:
Takes the string from "envVar" of type string (from a CANdb) -> copies the contents in "myString" of type char array, puts the number chars in "x" -> then write in the Write window of CANoe the string and length.

The snippet works if I input in the panel strings of > 4 characters. It does not work for strings of <= 4 chars (e.g. "abcd") and I do not understand why. For 1/2/3/4 characters input in my text field, my getValue method will put null in myString and x shall be 0. Where does this limit of 4 come from?

Additionally, I am using the same code snippet for the same purpose, but with myString2 declared as myString2[32] (not 17), and there, the limit goes from >4 to >9 -> "123456789" does not work, "0123456789" will work.

Any suggestions here?

Comment: You write something about a panel. How does the connection from panel to env-var look like? I.e. which control is used? What is the setup of the env-var in the dbc? When you enter `abcde` do you get `abcde` and `5`? You write _my getValue method_; is it CAPL's built-in `getValue` or something you have coded? Please be aware, that envVars are deprecated and subject to removal.

Comment: @MSpiller, I am using CANoe 11, with a panel that has a text editor control. To this control, I have assigned an environment variable of type "string".  When I enter 'abcde' in the text editor, I do get 'abcde' and '5', yes. If I enter 'abcd', I will get null and '0'. And yes, 'getValue' is CAPL built-in method which should put the value from the envVar attached to the text editor control into 'myString'. It works with >=5 chars, does not work with <5 chars.